# Using BeautifulSoup to find ID from Class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to return the ID of a cell to click using Selenium. The ID changes each time the page is loaded, so I'm trying to find the particular cell based off the class from:

`<table cellspacing="0" role="presentation" id="x-auto-667" class=" x-btn x-component x-btn-text-icon" style="margin-right: 0px;">`

I've tried many variations of:
soup.find(class=' x-btn x-component x-btn-text-icon')['id']

with no success. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Searching%20by%20CSS%20class), there is a shortcut for searching for CSS class: pass a string for the `attrs` parameter. Of course, you will have to give it a name when you do so, because otherwise the string will be misinterpreted as `name`. In short, you can find your table using `soup.find('', 'x-btn x-component x-btn-text-icon')`, and get at the `id` using:

```
soup.find('', 'x-btn x-component x-btn-text-icon')['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dict(soup.find('table', {'class' : ' x-btn x-component x-btn-text-icon'}).attrs)['id']
```

`class` is a keyword, so just cannot write `class = ...`. So there's the dictionary. You'll also need to cast the attributes collection to a dictionary to use `id` as a key.